# linking user-id and feedback-id after user login

Tags: php, mysql, feedback

Iam strugling with my issue to link user to his feedback he posted. I have feedback.php page and it is available for members and non-members to submit feedback to admin.
I have a feature where if user login and send feedback while he's loggedin, he will be able later-on to preview his feedbacks in his profile page.

I created 3 tables in my Dbase which are(**user**, **feedback**, **user-info**).

> User tbale has: ('userid' ,'fname', 'lname', 'username', 'email',
>   'password') userid(pk)
>
> feedback table has:('feedbackid' ,'feedbacktitle', 'name', 'email',
>   'comment', 'datetime') feedbackid (pk)
>
> user-info table has: ('id', 'feedback-id', 'user-id') id(pk)
>   feedback-id(fk) user-id(fk)

I tried to add (Fk) in user table and feedback table to display the user who sent the feedback but couldn't.
and then I created the user-info in attempts to get what I want but no-thing.

This is my feedback.php page:

> 

```
<?php
require('Connections/portdb.php');
//start session
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $feedbacktitle  = mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST['feedbacktitle']);
        $name  = mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST['name']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
        $datetime= mysql_real_escape_string (date ("y-m-d h:i:s")); //date time

$sql= "INSERT INTO feedback(feedbacktitle, name, email, comment, datetime)
VALUES('$feedbacktitle', '$name', '$email', '$comment', '$datetime')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<br>";

echo "<a href='../main.php'>Go back to main page</a>";
}
else {
echo "Sorry ! an error happend.";
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="css/styels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<title>Feedback Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php include("header.php")?> 

<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">

<table width="400" border="1" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">If you would like to contact us fill out the form below<br />
<br />
<form id="feedback-form" name="feedback-form" action="feedback.php" method="post">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Title:</td>
      <td align="left"><label for="email"></label>
        <input type="feedbacktitle" name="feedbacktitle" id="feedbacktitle"  size="30"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
      <td width="21%" align="right">Name:</td>
      <td width="79%" align="left"><label for="name"></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  size="30"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td align="right">Email:</td>
      <td align="left"><label for="email"></label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  size="30"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
      <td align="right">Message:</td>
      <td><label for="comments"></label>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="right"><input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      </tr>

  </table>
</form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
        </div>
       </div>
<?php include("right-side.php")?>
<?php include("footer.php")?> 
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my login.php

```
 <?php
//start session
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}
    include("Connections/portdb.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string (md5($_POST['password']));

$getLogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password = '$password' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($getLogin);

if(mysql_num_rows($getLogin) > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['loggedin']= true;
    $_SESSION['userid']= $row['userid'];
    $_SESSION['username']= $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['usertype']= 'user';
    session_write_close();
    header("location: main.php");
}
else
{
    header("location:login-user.php?msg=1");
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>User Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php include("header.php")?> 
        <div id="wrapper">

<table width="915" height="700" border="2" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" bordercolor="#003399">
  <tr>
    <td width="627" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#A7E9DA"><p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><b>Welcome Guest ! Please fill the fields below to login<br />
        <br />
      </b></p>
      <?php
      if(isset($_GET['msg']))
      {
          $message = $_GET['msg'];
          if($message == 1)
            echo "<span style='color:red'>Username or Password is wroong";
      }
      ?>
      <form id="userloginform" name="userloginform" action="login-user.php"  method="post">
        <table width="46%" border="3" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
    <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
      <td width="21%" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Username:</td>
      <td width="79%" align="left" bgcolor="#99CC99"><label for="username"></label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="30" size="30"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Password:</td>
      <td align="left" bgcolor="#99CC99"><label for="password"></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  maxlength="128" size="30"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC66"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="132" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><p><a href="forget-passowrd.php">Forgot Your Password ?</a></p>
        <p><a href="register.php">New Member ?</a></p>
        </td>
      </tr>

  </table>
</form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
       </div>

<?php include("footer.php")?>        
</body>
</html>
```

That what I have. I tried a lot to solve and couldn't. can someone tell me if Iam doing wrong or what should I add. Iam not an expert just new to this and try to learn.

Thanks alot in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

You should link the feedback and the user at the time of submittion, after inserting to the feedback table you need to also insert into the user-info table if the user is logged in

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO feedback
       (feedbacktitle, name, email, comment, datetime)
       VALUES('$feedbacktitle', '$name', '$email', '$comment', '$datetime')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result) {
   $feedbackid = mysql_insert_id();
   if(isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) {
       $uid = $_SESSION['userid'];
       $uinfo_sql = "INSERT INTO user-info
       (feedbackid, userid)
       VALUES('$feedbackid','$uid')";
       $uinfoResult = mysql_query($uinfo_sql);
       //etc etc
   }       
}
```

Comment: Erman Belegu, I Am really speechless. I spent 2 days reading and searching for an answer, tried different kind of solutions but couldn't get it.

Thanks alot, May God bless you brother. ^_^